# JSF Create embedded browser nested

Tags: jsf

I need to create a web site and open a another web html inside(nested), the html must to be inside a composite. Any idea?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition template="./welcomePrimefaces.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:define name="contenido">
external web site????? 
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ui:composition>
```

allows you to include JSF templates which have code snippets. These templates must be avialble within the same classloader.

If you want to embed an external page into your page, you need to use iframe.

For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf"/>
```

You can place this on the page and point it to the external website.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Comment: No problem, just mark your solution as fixed and vote my post by clicking on the up arrow! Cheers